# Is it possible to hide save errors in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I programmed a spreadsheet to be saved and always replace the original file in a location on my company's network. But as the wi-fi sometimes crashes, Excel can not save to the specified location and ends up returning the error as the image. Is it possible to hide this error and move on?[image: Error]
(Translated by Bing Translate)

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

And

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Don't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect that a statement might fail, you can catch the error by yourself by setting `On Error Resume Next` - but don't forget to put the statement `On Error Goto 0` after that statement.

Of course if the save fails, the workbook stays unsafed and you need to take care about it. You can check if a workbook was modified after the last (successfull) save with the `Saved` property.

```
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "X:\junk", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
' Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description  ' It's a 1004 error
On Error GoTo 0
if not ThisWorkbook.Saved then msgBox "Failed to save workbook."
```